# What's the dual problem of this quadratic programming problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, quadratic-programming

$$\min\left(\sum_{i=0}^n  \sum_{j=0}^n  ((V_i)_j)x_ix_j\right)$$
subject to
$$x_1 + \dots + x_n = 1,$$ $$m_1x_1 + \dots + m_nx_n = m,$$ $$x_i \ge 0$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What have you tried to do? Have you tried to dualize it using the well-known, standard, existing method.

Comment: @KBS Do you mean with the Lagrangian?

Comment: Yes, for instance.